# Angularjs website footer won't touch the bottom. <body> background stays below footer

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi I'm struggling to get a footer partial to touch the bottom of the website.

As you can see in the screenshot...there's a cyan strip (part of body background colour) below the grey footer bar...I don't want it there.  I would like the **grey footer partial to touch the very bottom.**  I've messed around the code for hours and can't get it to touch the bottom.

Thanks.

[image: screenshot1]

I've tried using

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Here's a part of index.html

```
    <html>
    <body>



 <!--HEADER AND NAVBAR -->


<!--MAIN PARTIAL-->
<div ui-view class=""></div>


</div>
</div>


<!--Footer Partial -->
  <div id="footer" ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the footer partial code.
footer.html

```
<div class="footer">



 <ul class="links">
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/clearfinance"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com/OilRecCandidate"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/clearfin1"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/116852466188350790084/auto"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/105027?trk=cws-btn-overview-0-0"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        </ul>


Text goes here
</div>
```

This is a part of style.css

```
/* general settings */
html {
 min-height:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
background-color:#0783A9;

}
body {
  background-color:#0783A9;
  font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; color:#c4c4c4; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.19em;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:100;
  margin:0px;
 min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
    }

.footer {
     background-color: #cecece;
     color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;

}
```

Comment: What do you have if you use `position: fixed` for the footer ?

Comment: I don't want it fixed when the user scrolls.

But I have tried it...it makes the footer go further higher up below the main view.

The cyan bit stays underneath.